# Can I pass a pattern into a function?

Tags: haskell

I want a function like following, is this possible?
in fact, I don't know if the type Pattern exists.

```
fun1 a :: Pattern a -> a -> Bool
fun1 pattern a = case a of
    pattern -> True
    _ -> False
```

Comment: I don't speak F#, but I think [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) can do something similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the Functional Pearl, [Type Safe Pattern Combinators](http://www.itu.dk/people/mir/typesafepatterns.pdf). A bit of Googling shows that there is a [Hackage package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/first-class-patterns/) based on it as well.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think this is possible in Haskell.

However, in your case, the pattern is effectively just a function of type `a -> Bool`. So instead of accepting a pattern, accept any function from `a` to `Bool`. You example is equivalent to applying a function `a -> Bool` on an `a`.

Now, if you wanted to do something more general, like being able to use the matched symbols from the pattern in the body of `fun1`, you would not be able to do it with a function. However, I doubt this is possible with Haskell at all--it would require weird extensions to the type system to make any sense. Pattern matching in Haskell is not a first-class citizen at all, so you can't really pass patterns around like that.

If you want this kind of behavior, check out the book [*Pattern Calculus*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540891846) where the author develops and formalizes a language with more general pattern-matching features than Haskell. It makes patterns a first-class citizen, unlike Haskell. I haven't actually finished this book yet, but I'm pretty sure that code like that is exactly what you would be able to write, among other things.

The author built a language around his ideas about pattern matching called [bondi](http://bondi.it.uts.edu.au/); it's probably also worth checking out, especially if you don't want to bother with the book. I don't know if it's ready for practical use, but it's certainly interesting.

Comment: ghc has this ViewPattern extension since version 6.10 (04-Nov-2008). With that syntactic extension, those "Pattern"s are just functions mapping from the value-to-be-analyzed to the result-to-be-further-pattern-matched.

Comment: @comonad: I'm not sure that the ViewPattern extension is applicable here--it lets you use functions as patterns where the OP wants to use patterns as functions.

Comment: I was referring to your second section: "…, like being able to use the matched symbols from the pattern in the body of fun1, you would not be able to do it with a function." Well, using ViewPatterns, that function/pattern has to return the matched bindings so that the caller can bind them to his own variables or to pattern match them further. If that would be too verbose (and if I remember correctly), there exists a trick with RecordWildcards that lets you combine specific named variables to one value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are looking for **View Patterns**.

(see [trac/ghc/wiki](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) or [ghc/user-manual/syntax-extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns))

---

Every function is a "Pattern":

```
case "string that ends with x" of
    (last->'x') -> True
    _ -> False

case "foo" of
    (elemIndex 'g'->Just i) -> i+5
    (elemIndex 'f'->Nothing) -> 23
    _ -> 42

do
  x <- fmap foo bar
=
do
  (foo->x) <- bar
```

Comment: I think he was asking for the opposite--instead of using functions as patterns, he wanted to use patterns as functions. So he wanted to be able to call `fun1 (Just x) a` and match the value of `a` against the *pattern* `Just x`. This is what the library linked in the accepted answer lets you do. I don't think ViewPatterns let you do that though.

Comment: Tikhon Jelvis: Interesting, didn't consider that view. Actually, Jason asked for using patterns as patterns. But to make a function out of a pattern is trivial. AFAIC Jason is new to Stackoverflow and just accepted any answer without commenting it; I'm not so sure that he wanted only one specific answer.